# Command out of sync error on nested quires

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

i am directly using `SQL` tab in PHPMyAdmin to execute my query, but still getting the same error `Command out of sync error` here is my MySQL query i'm trying to execute:

```
SELECT `courses`.`id`               as `courseId`, 
       `courses`.`Name`             as `courseName`, 
       `course2teacher`.`TeacherId` as `teacherId`, 
       (SELECT user.name 
        FROM   user, 
               (SELECT course2teacher.TeacherId as tid 
                FROM   course2teacher, 
                       user, 
                       follows, 
                       teachers 
                WHERE  user.id = 10 
                       AND user.id = follows.studentid 
                       AND course2teacher.id = follows.course2teacherid) as 
               teach 
        WHERE  teach.tid = user.id) as teacherName, 
       `assignments`.`Assignment#`  AS `assignmentName`, 
       `assignments`.`DueDate`      AS `duedate`, 
       `assignments`.`DueTime`      AS `duetime`, 
       `assignments`.`expiryDate`   AS `expiryDate` 
FROM   `teachers`, 
       `courses`, 
       `assignments`, 
       `course2teacher`, 
       `user`,
       `follows`
WHERE  `user`.`id` = '10' 
       AND `user`.`id` = `follows`.`studentid` 
       AND `follows`.`course2teacherid` = `assignments`.`course2teacherId` 
       AND `course2teacher`.`id` = `follows`.`course2teacherid`
```

this is error message i get: `#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`

why this is occurring ,and is there any way to fix it?

Comment: What version of phpMyAdmin?

Comment: phpmyadmin version is 4.0.10.14

Comment: I think that, whatever way you cut this, it must be a bug in phpMyAdmin—exactly what circumstances trigger it and how it can be avoided are different questions, however...

Comment: but I care less about bug , but my query ! , if there is anything wrong with my query kindly tell me

Comment: can the query run correctly in terminal? plz try it first

Comment: it's not running correctly as i've mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Z

This error normally occurs when a result set is opened and then not closed before another query is launched.

This I believe would recreate your error (minimal example for illustrative purposes):

```
$CMySQL->query($VSQL);

$RResult = $CMySQL->store_result();

$ARow = $RResult->fetch_assoc();

$CMySQL->query($VSQL); // error occurs here as result set is still open
```

To solve this the following code could be used:

```
$CMySQL->query($VSQL);

$RResult = $CMySQL->store_result();

$ARow = $RResult->fetch_assoc();

$RResult->free();

$CMySQL->next_result()

$CMySQL->query($VSQL); // should work now
```

To summarise I don't think the cause of your error is in the query, rather something that happened earlier on in your code and caused your MySQL connection to become jammed open. To determine this as mentioned by 麦伟锋 you can try running the query in a standalone client, or if you want to do in code, open a new connection just for this query to see if the error reoccurs.

Regards,

James

Comment: problem is forget about code , i'm running this query in phpmyadmin , if you think it is code issue then phpmyadmin defiantly have some bug

Comment: Have you logged in from fresh in phpmyadmin and tried it as the first command? I'd never expect this from a single query run against the database. If you want to post some test data I'll run this query for you strait against a db through the terminal. As you can see from the docs, its completely miscellaneous for this error message to occur in this scenario. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commands-out-of-sync.html

Comment: well error have occurred as you can see , and my data is somewhat confidential , so can't share it , and yes i've tried it as first command after fresh login , didn't work though same error

Comment: Please make up some test data, it needs to consist of a table create, insert and your original query (above), if I can run it then the hypothesis that your query is not the issue remains unbroken and we can work together to isolate further issues. Happy to provide guidelines if needed.